# How to reformat my Java code from JDK8 to JDK16?

Tags: java, java-8

I have the following method:

```
public static File[] getFileListFromDirByDate(String Dir,final boolean byAscendingDate)
{
    if (!new File(Dir).isDirectory()) return null;
    File files[]=new File(Dir).listFiles();
    Arrays.sort(files,new Comparator() { public int compare(final Object o1,final Object o2) { return byAscendingDate?new Long(((File)o1).lastModified()).compareTo(new Long(((File) o2).lastModified())):new Long(((File)o2).lastModified()).compareTo(new Long(((File) o1).lastModified())); } });
    return files;
}
```

It used to be OK with JDK8, but now I'm compiling with JDK16, I got the following message:

```
warning: [removal] Long(long) in Long has been deprecated and marked for removal
```

Comment: Use [`Long.valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Long.html#valueOf(long)). There are some more things you might want to do, but this will get rid of the warning.

Comment: from [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Long.html#%3Cinit%3E(long)) of `Long(long)`: "**Deprecated, for removal: This API element is subject to removal in a future version.** It is rarely appropriate to use this constructor. The static factory `valueOf(long)` is generally a better choice, ...'

Comment: This is not 'reformatting'.  But aside from that, how many need fixing?  I'd guess that a global replace of 'new Long(' by 'Long.valueOf(' will take you most of the way.  It's a one-liner in sed or Perl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the general case, you can use [`Long::valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Long.html#valueOf(long)). But in this case specifically, you should take the time to simplify the code in general. The code you have is more reminiscent of Java 1.4 (before generics) than of Java 8, even.

Here's your comparator, nicely formatted:

```
new Comparator() {
    public int compare(final Object o1,final Object o2) {
        return byAscendingDate
            ? new Long(((File)o1).lastModified()).compareTo(new Long(((File) o2).lastModified()))
            : new Long(((File)o2).lastModified()).compareTo(new Long(((File) o1).lastModified()));
        }
    });
```

First, use the generic form instead of a raw `Comparator`. This remove the need for casts:

```
new Comparator<File>() { // use generic instead of raw
    public int compare(final File o1, final File o2) { // File instead of Object
        return byAscendingDate
            ? new Long(o1.lastModified()).compareTo(new Long(o2.lastModified()))
            : new Long(o2.lastModified()).compareTo(new Long(o1.lastModified()));
        }
    });
```

Now, instead of `new Long(...).compareTo` or even `Long.valueOf(...).compareTo`, you can just use the [`static Long::compare(long, long)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Long.html#compare(long,long)) introduced in Java 7:

```
new Comparator<File>() { // use generic instead of raw
    public int compare(final File o1, final File o2) { // File instead of Object
        return byAscendingDate
            ? Long.compare(o1.lastModified(), o2.lastModified())
            : Long.compare(o2.lastModified(), o1.lastModified())
        }
    });
```

Then, you can use lambdas instead of an anonymous class:

```
(o1, o2) -> byAscendingDate
     ? Long.compare(o1.lastModified(), o2.lastModified())
     : Long.compare(o2.lastModified(), o1.lastModified())
```

Or, you can even just use the `Comparator` helpers introduced in Java 8. Combining [`Comparator::comparingLong`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#comparingLong(java.util.function.ToLongFunction)) and [`Comparator::reversed`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#reversed()), you get:

```
Comparator<File> cmp = Comparator.comparingLong(File::lastModified);
if (!byAscendingDate) {
    cmp = cmp.reversed();
}
Arrays.sort(files, cmp);
```

I would encourage you to look around the Comparator and Long classes to see what new functions are around, and in general to keep an eye out for the various helpers that have been introduced over the years.

Comment: Almost perfect ^_^ ! Thanks !   [ if (!byAscendingDate) { cmp = cmp.reversed(); } ]

Comment: @Frank Whoops, good catch! I've been programming lately in languages that don't require the parens, and I guess it's been sticky! :-)

Comment: Well, on my side, I thought maybe the latest Java version doesn't require them, so I tried your code, got error lol ^_^ ! But thanks for the detailed examples, very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the *[Long#valueOf](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Long.html#valueOf(long))* method, as per the *JavaDoc* specification.

*[Long – Constructor Details (Java SE 20 & JDK 20)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Long.html#%3Cinit%3E(long))*.

> *"**Deprecated, for removal: This API element is subject to removal in a future version.**
>
> It is rarely appropriate to use this constructor. The static factory valueOf(long) is generally a better choice, as it is likely to yield significantly better space and time performance."*.

Although, since you are comparing two *long* primitive values, you can just use the *[Long#compare](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Long.html#compare(long,long))* method.
This will remove the need to create a *Long* object.

Additionally, you can replace the anonymous-inner class, *Comparator*, with a *[closure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html)*.

```java
Arrays.sort(files, (Comparator<File>) (o1, o2) -> byAscendingDate
    ? Long.compare(o1.lastModified(), o2.lastModified())
    : Long.compare(o2.lastModified(), o1.lastModified()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Long.valueOf()` instead of `new Long()`.